# MatPlotLib and PyQt plot and additional data to printer

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a bar plot and additional data that I am showing in a PyQt MainWindow. I need to be able to print this plot and data on paper, but don't know how to go about it.

I know how to save the plot to a pdf using `print_figure` and then send to a printer, but this does not allow me to place the additional data on the same piece of page as the plot. I have looked around and cannot find a way to get the plot with the data printed below it together on one page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text_str = '''Some additional very long text
that spans over a few lines and is
very very very very very boring
but it's sole purpose is demonstration
so we can live with that'''

# make figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
# shove the bottom of the axes up
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=.3)
# add the text
fig.text(0, 0, text_str, va='bottom')
# force draw
plt.draw()
```

[image]